# Windows service fails to start up with "Error 5: Access is denied"

Tags: powershell, windows-services, access-denied, user-permissions

I am struggling with a problem here.
So I've created a windows service, made the install script and registered it with Windows. I am using a custom account that I create in that same script, and give it rights to "log on as a service" using a Carbon library to be able to do so from PowerShell (described [here](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Set-or-Grant-Logon-As-A-Service-right-to-User.html) under "Set or Grant User Logon As A Service right via Powershell")

On starting the service (both manually and through cmd), I get "Error 5: Access is denied" error. I don't understand why though, I've even tried giving the account full permissions to the whole C:\ drive.

Here's how I create the user

```
net user MyServiceAccount MyPassword /add /expires:never /passwordchg:no
```

Here's how I grant it permission to log on as a service

```
$Identity = "MyServiceAccount"
$privilege = "SeServiceLogonRight" 
$CarbonDllPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\Carbon.dll"
 
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($CarbonDllPath)
[Carbon.Lsa]::GrantPrivileges( $Identity, $privilege )
```

(Log on as service permissions seem to work, since before it failed with an error regarding that issue)
I've read through a big bunch of posts on the topic, but couldn't resolve the issue.
So, again, my question is: what could be causing the Access is denied error?

## update

Tried to run it under administrator account (log on as...), it does the same thing - Access is denied. EventLog has nothing except the "The MonitoringService service failed to start due to the following error: Access is denied." message in System event log.

Comment: Probably access denied error is thrown vs some registry key instead of a file.

Comment: @Vesper is there a way to find out? I mean, how can I get an idea of what registry key it might be failing against?

Comment: Your app should provide logs and/or other debug info, so that it'll not panic with a raw 0xC0000005 on top of stack trace. If you're in control of its code, make sure you've got try-catch on any external operation so that it won't just end up in panic. If not, use Sysinternals Process Monitor, regmon and filemon tools to record registry activity and debug the application.

Comment: @Vesper I've excluded all of my code from the service leaving just the standard start-up initialization. And just tried Sysinternals ProcessMonitor with no yield. The service crashes immidiately, so I don't think it's possible to somehow debug it, no?

Comment: Any clues in the security event logs on the server?

Comment: @mjolinor nothing... just this in the System event log:
The MonitoringService service failed to start due to the following error: Access is denied.

Comment: @JurijsKastanovs Even if it crashes at once, you might see process ID in logs of filemon+regmon accessing a file or registry with failure. Also, try adding the service via `sc add` command, then reassign it to be run under a specific user, then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've managed to resolve my problem by using a different installation routine for the service. It appears it was a problem of installation rather than user rights related problem. Below is the example of a working script in case anyone is interested:

```
# ALISE MONITORING SERVICE INSTALLATION #

$service_fullname = "Alise.MonitoringService"
$username = ".\AliseMonitoring"
$password = "mypassword"
$pause = 0
$exeName = "MonitoringService.exe"

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine

$dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$service_path = join-path $dir "$exeName"
$service_path = resolve-path $service_path


Write-Host $nl
Write-Host "Service name: $service_fullname" -foregroundcolor green
Write-Host "Service logon identity: $username" -foregroundcolor green
Write-Host "Service installation path: $service_path" -foregroundcolor green
Write-Host $nl

Write-Host "Creating user if necessary..." -foregroundcolor green
start-process create_user.bat -Wait
Write-Host "Granting user log on as service rights..." -foregroundcolor green
$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Identity = "AliseMonitoring"
$privilege = "SeServiceLogonRight" 
$CarbonDllPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\Carbon.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($CarbonDllPath)
[Carbon.Lsa]::GrantPrivileges( $Identity, $privilege )
Write-Host $nl

$service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = '$service_fullname'"
if ($service -ne $null) 
{ 
    Write-Host "Service already exists, attempting stop and delete:" -foregroundcolor green
    Write-Host "Stop service $service_fullname..."
    $service | stop-service
    Write-Host "Delete service $service_fullname..."
    $service.Delete()
    Write-Host "Service $service_fullname deleted." 
    Write-Host $nl
}

Write-Host $nl

Write-Host "Registering service $service_fullname for $service_path ..." -foregroundcolor green
New-Service -Name $service_fullname -BinaryPathName $service_path -DisplayName $service_fullname -Description "Alise monitoring serviss." -StartupType Automatic
$service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = '$service_fullname'"
Write-Host "Service registred."

$res = sc.exe config $service_fullname obj= $username password= $password

if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
   Write-Host "username: $username password: $password" -foregroundcolor green
   throw $res
}

#Event log and source registration
Write-Host $nl
Write-Host "Registering event source Alise.MonitoringService" -foregroundcolor green
if ([system.diagnostics.eventlog]::SourceExists("Alise.MonitoringService") -eq $false) 
{
  [system.diagnostics.eventlog]::CreateEventSource("Alise.MonitoringService", "Alise")
  Write-Host "Created event source: Alise.MonitoringService"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Event source Alise.MonitoringService allready exists."
}

Write-Host $nl
Write-Host "Starting service..." -foregroundcolor green
Start-Service $service_fullname
Write-Host "Service started!" -foregroundcolor green

if ($pause -eq 1)
{
    read-host -prompt "Press enter to exit"
}
```